# Задать позицию UI элементу в ItemsControl

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Есть `Grid`, которому нужно биндить позицию, но я не пойму как это сделать, если `Canvas` лежит `ItemsPanel`, к нему можно как то обратиться? Написанные мной `Canvas.Top` и `Canvas.Top` не дают эффекта

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Control" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageManipulatorViewModel.ImageList, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Name="RootPanel">
            <Canvas x:Name="InnerCanvas"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Collage">
                <Grid
                    <!--Canvas.Top="{Binding  PositionY, Mode=TwoWay}"-->
                    <!--Canvas.Left="{Binding PositionX, Mode=TwoWay}"-->
                     />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно делать, как описано в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437054/10105):

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding PositionX}"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding PositionY}"/>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Collage">
        <Grid> <!-- тут всё остальное --> </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Надеюсь, что в UWP есть `ItemContainerStyle`.

---

Обновление: По слухам, `Binding` не всегда работает в `Setter`'е стиля в UWP, так что возможно, вам придётся воспользоваться костылём [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40069980/276994):

```
<!-- не устанавливаем ItemContainerStyle -->
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Collage">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="{Binding PositionX}" Y="{Binding PositionY}"/>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <!-- тут всё остальное -->
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: В первом случае жалуется на `DataContext`, который установлен только в `DataTemplate`. Второй сейчас провверю

Comment: Второй метод расставляет `Grid`'ы как нужно, но теперь не работает `Manipulation` не не могу таскать по экрану, потому что в коде при обработке делаю `Canvas.SetLeft/Top()`

Comment: Нужно теперь двигать через `Translate`

Comment: @SmiLe: Если вы двигаете при манипуляции, просто устанавливайте `PositionX/Y`, и контрол по идее подвинется сам.

Comment: CompisiteTransform.TranslateX/Y. Вот так двигается. А posX/Y не могу напрямую менять, они же в моделе

Comment: @SmiLe: Вот [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508647/10105) MVVM-решение похожей проблемы.